# Telegram get messages history

Tags: http, dart, web-scraping, telegram-bot

Telegram **In Dart or http request**

How to get group all messages by using dart or http

*Note that* I have my bot token and I wanna use it in dart ("No another Languages") or http

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, are you asking how to get old messages from a group?

Comment: @GioIacca9 yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't get old messages from a group with the Bots API.

You can save every message in a database for a later use, but old messages are not accessible. The only way is by using the [client API](https://core.telegram.org/schema).